# How to exlude uncategorized posts using WP_Query?

Tags: wordpress

I have this line:

```
$exclude = array(22, 34, 1);

$cat_query = new WP_Query(array ( 'posts_per_page' => 100 , 'category__not_in' => $exclude));
```

And I want to know how to exclude Uncategorized posts from this, I already tried using 0, 1 and 'Uncategorized' but I get the same result with the other categories excluded but some uncategorized posts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your posts has multiple categories?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$cat_query = new WP_Query(
    array (
        'posts_per_page' => 100 ,
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy'  => 'category',
                'field'     => 'slug',
                'terms'     => 'uncategorized',
                'operator'  => 'NOT IN'
            )
        )
    )
);
```